# all features must be in [0, 9] or [-10, 0]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
df = load_data()
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df.dtypes

intBillID                      object
chBillChargeCode               object
chBillNo                       object
chOriginalBillNo               object
sdBillDate             datetime64[ns]
sdDueDate              datetime64[ns]
sdDatePaidCancelled    datetime64[ns]
sdBillCancelledDate            object
totalDaysToPay                  int64
paidInDays                      int64
paidOnTime                      int64
chBillStatus                   object
chBillType                     object
chDebtorCode                   object
chBillGroupCode                 int64
dcTotFeeBilledAmt             float64
dcFinalBillExpAmt             float64
dcTotProgBillAmt              float64
dcTotProgBillExpAmt           float64
dcReceiveBillAmt              float64
dcTotWipHours                 float64
dcTotWipTargetAmt             float64
vcReason                       object
OperatingUnit                  object
BusinessUnit                   object
LosCode                        object
dcTotNetBillAmt               float64
dtype: object
```

Then I have this:

```
# Separate features and labels
X, y = df[['totalDaysToPay', 'paidOnTime','dcTotFeeBilledAmt','dcFinalBillExpAmt','dcTotProgBillAmt', 'dcTotProgBillExpAmt','dcTotProgBillExpAmt','dcReceiveBillAmt','dcTotWipHours','dcTotWipTargetAmt']].values, df['paidInDays'].values
print('Features:',X[:10], '\nLabels:', y[:10], sep='\n')
```

then I split X,Y

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

```
# Split data 70%-30% into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)

print ('Training Set: %d rows\nTest Set: %d rows' % (X_train.shape[0], X_test.shape[0]))
```

Then I want to transform numeric and categorial features:

```
# Train the model
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

# Define preprocessing for numeric columns (scale them)
numeric_features = [8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,26]
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

# Define preprocessing for categorical features (encode them)
categorical_features = [1,23,24,25]
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

# Combine preprocessing steps
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

# Create preprocessing and training pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                           ('regressor', GradientBoostingRegressor())])


# fit the pipeline to train a linear regression model on the training set
model = pipeline.fit(X_train, (y_train))
print (model)
```

However I get this error:

```
ValueError: all features must be in [0, 9] or [-10, 0]
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, same index range 0-9. I only have 10 features, and I only use 0-9 to reference them in ColumnTransform. Any idea why that might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line, you are selecting 10 features for X, so the shape of X is changed now.

```
# Separate features and labels
X, y = df[['totalDaysToPay', 'paidOnTime','dcTotFeeBilledAmt','dcFinalBillExpAmt','dcTotProgBillAmt', 'dcTotProgBillExpAmt','dcTotProgBillExpAmt','dcReceiveBillAmt','dcTotWipHours','dcTotWipTargetAmt']].values, df['paidInDays'].values
```

Now, you need to give indexes of '`numeric_features`' according to the range [0-9].
To be more specific, the indexes you are passing in '`numeric features`' should reflect this array.

```
['totalDaysToPay', 'paidOnTime','dcTotFeeBilledAmt','dcFinalBillExpAmt','dcTotProgBillAmt', 'dcTotProgBillExpAmt','dcTotProgBillExpAmt','dcReceiveBillAmt','dcTotWipHours','dcTotWipTargetAmt']
```

This array is correct for the origial '`df`': `[8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,26]` not for `X`.

Comment: understood, I changed this line: numeric_features = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].  However I still have the same error, I suppose is regarding the categorial features, how can I fix that part

Comment: you don't have any categorical feature in X, so I'd say skip it. If you didn't intend to skip those features, change the list_of_columns where you are creating X, y = df[ list_of_cols ]

Comment: I'm getting the same error, same index range 0-9. I only have 10 features, and I only use 0-9 to reference them in ColumnTransform. Any idea why that might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yh. @Luis Valencia, I think the problem is coming from the one-hot encoding which will create new columns for as many unique values of a categorical feature there are, which in turn changes the shape of the output, making it differ from the input you gave it.
So unless you're willing to change your type of encoding then you have to preprocess the categorical data without using the pipeline.

**For example**:
`encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)`
`encoded = encoder.fit_transform(target_train)`

*encoded* will have a different shape from *target_train*, with *encoded* having more columns.