# ValueError: all features must be in [0, 20] or [-21, 0]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

```
data_df_cleaned.info()

Data columns (total 23 columns):
 #   Column                    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                    --------------  -----  
 0   id                        59884 non-null  int64  
 1   age                       59884 non-null  float64
 2   occupation                59884 non-null  object 
 3   annual_income             59884 non-null  float64
 4   monthly_inhand_salary     59884 non-null  float64
 5   num_bank_accounts         59884 non-null  float64
 6   num_credit_card           59884 non-null  float64
 7   interest_rate             59884 non-null  float64
 8   num_of_loan               59884 non-null  float64
 9   type_of_loan              59884 non-null  object 
 10  delay_from_due_date       59884 non-null  float64
 11  num_of_delayed_payment    59884 non-null  float64
 12  changed_credit_limit      59884 non-null  float64
 13  num_credit_inquiries      59884 non-null  float64
 14  credit_mix                59884 non-null  object 
 15  outstanding_debt          59884 non-null  float64
 16  credit_utilization_ratio  59884 non-null  float64
 17  credit_history_age        59884 non-null  float64
 18  payment_of_min_amount     59884 non-null  object 
 19  amount_invested_monthly   59884 non-null  float64
...
 21  monthly_balance           59884 non-null  float64
 22  credit_score              59884 non-null  object 
dtypes: float64(16), int64(1), object(6)
memory usage: 11.0+ MB


from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
data_df_cleaned['occupation'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data_df_cleaned['occupation'])
data_df_cleaned['type_of_loan'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data_df_cleaned['type_of_loan'])
data_df_cleaned['credit_mix'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data_df_cleaned['credit_mix'])
data_df_cleaned['payment_behaviour'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data_df_cleaned['payment_behaviour'])
data_df_cleaned['payment_of_min_amount'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data_df_cleaned['payment_of_min_amount'])

data_df_cleaned.info()

Data columns (total 23 columns):
 #   Column                    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                    --------------  -----  
 0   id                        59884 non-null  int64  
 1   age                       59884 non-null  float64
 2   occupation                59884 non-null  int32  
 3   annual_income             59884 non-null  float64
 4   monthly_inhand_salary     59884 non-null  float64
 5   num_bank_accounts         59884 non-null  float64
 6   num_credit_card           59884 non-null  float64
 7   interest_rate             59884 non-null  float64
 8   num_of_loan               59884 non-null  float64
 9   type_of_loan              59884 non-null  int32  
 10  delay_from_due_date       59884 non-null  float64
 11  num_of_delayed_payment    59884 non-null  float64
 12  changed_credit_limit      59884 non-null  float64
 13  num_credit_inquiries      59884 non-null  float64
 14  credit_mix                59884 non-null  int32  
 15  outstanding_debt          59884 non-null  float64
 16  credit_utilization_ratio  59884 non-null  float64
 17  credit_history_age        59884 non-null  float64
 18  payment_of_min_amount     59884 non-null  int32  
 19  amount_invested_monthly   59884 non-null  float64
...
 21  monthly_balance           59884 non-null  float64
 22  credit_score              59884 non-null  object 
dtypes: float64(16), int32(5), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 9.8+ MB

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder

pipeline=ColumnTransformer([
    ('num',StandardScaler(),[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,19,21]), # Encoding numerical variables
    ('cat',OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),[2,9,14,18,20]), # Encoding categorical variables
])

# Now that the pipeline is set and ready we can use it to transform our data

X = data_df_cleaned.iloc[:, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]].values #independent variables
y = data_df_cleaned.iloc[:, 22].values #dependent variables

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

X_train = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = pipeline.transform(X_test)

IndexError: index 21 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 21
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-388-64cb46e4a9e0> in <module>
----> 1 X_train = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)
      2 X_test = pipeline.transform(X_test)
...
--> 367             raise ValueError(
    368                 'all features must be in [0, {}] or [-{}, 0]'
    369                 .format(n_columns - 1, n_columns)

ValueError: all features must be in [0, 20] or [-21, 0]
```

Hi everyone, this is part of a ml project and I'm facing such problem. I tried to fix it in many ways, but I didn't manage to do it. May you please help me?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789613/all-features-must-be-in-0-9-or-10-0)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use column names with `ColumnTransformer` where possible, they should be more robust than selecting with integer indexes.

Here the `pipe` might be replaced with something like this:

```py
pipe = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", StandardScaler(), ["three"]),
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), ["one", "two"]),
])
```

---

Here's a minimal way to reproduce this behavior with comments:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "label": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    "one":   ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"],
    "two":   [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    "three": [0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 0.7]})

X, y = df.drop(["label"], axis=1), df["label"]         # Selection changes indexes

pipe = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", StandardScaler(), [3]),                    # <-- Should now be '2'
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), [1, 2]),
]).fit(X, y)
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 414, in _get_column_indices
    idx = _safe_indexing(np.arange(n_columns), key)
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 356, in _safe_indexing
    return _array_indexing(X, indices, indices_dtype, axis=axis)
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 185, in _array_indexing
    return array[key] if axis == 0 else array[:, key]
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hayesall/Teaching/stackoverflow/features_in_range.py", line 13, in <module>
    pipe = ColumnTransformer([
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 693, in fit
    self.fit_transform(X, y=y)
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py", line 142, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 723, in fit_transform
    self._validate_column_callables(X)
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 425, in _validate_column_callables
    transformer_to_input_indices[name] = _get_column_indices(X, columns)
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 416, in _get_column_indices
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: all features must be in [0, 2] or [-3, 0]
```