# Combining sequential feature selection with column transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

I am trying to implement a pipeline with sklearn combining a column transformer for numeric and categorical data and sequential feature selection. The issue is when doing the complete pipeline it gets an error.

Code:

```
X = data_features
y = data_labels

# To have the name of all the features
features_name = list(data_features.columns)
# To have the name of the categorical features
categorical_features = ['sex','num_comorbidities','sarcopenia','osteoporosis']
categorical_features_idx = [features_name.index(i) for i in categorical_features]
# To have the numeric features
numeric_features = [feature for feature in features_name if feature not in categorical_features]
numeric_features_idx = [features_name.index(i) for i in numeric_features]    

'''To have the data pre-procesing steps'''
#To create separated pipelines for categorical and numeric variables

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [
                                            ('scaler1', QuantileTransformer(n_quantiles = 20,        output_distribution = 'normal', random_state = 1)),
                                            ('scaler2', Normalizer())                                            
                                        ])
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [
                                                ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(categories = 'auto', handle_unknown='ignore'))
                                                
                                            ])
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [
                                                    ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numeric_features_idx),
                                                    ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features_idx)                                                            
                                                ])
pipe = Pipeline(steps = [
                            ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                            ('tomekU', SMOTETomek(tomek = TomekLinks(sampling_strategy = 'majority'))),
                            ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100,
                                                                  criterion = 'gini',
                                                                  max_depth = 90,
                                                                  max_features = 'auto',
                                                                  min_samples_leaf = 3,
                                                                  min_samples_split = 10,                                                                  
                                                                  bootstrap = True,
                                                                  class_weight = 'balanced'))
                        ])

'''To do feature selection'''
sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(pipe, n_features_to_select = 20, direction = 'backward', scoring = 'roc_auc', cv = 20)
X_transformed = sfs.fit_transform(X, np.ravel(y))
```

I get the following error at the last line above

```
ValueError: all features must be in \[0, 156\] or \[-157, 0\]
```

I have the following data:\

```
X.shape:\
(414, 158)

y.shape:\
(414, 1)

categorical_features_idx:\
\[0, 2, 3, 4\]

numeric_features_idx:\
[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157\]
```

**Traceback**

```
{
    "name": "ValueError",
    "message": "
All the 5 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\__init__.py\", line 414, in _get_column_indices
    idx = _safe_indexing(np.arange(n_columns), key)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\__init__.py\", line 356, in _safe_indexing
    return _array_indexing(X, indices, indices_dtype, axis=axis)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\__init__.py\", line 185, in _array_indexing
    return array[key] if axis == 0 else array[:, key]
IndexError: index 157 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 157

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\model_selection\\_validation.py\", line 686, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\imblearn\\pipeline.py\", line 293, in fit
    Xt, yt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\imblearn\\pipeline.py\", line 240, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\joblib\\memory.py\", line 349, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\pipeline.py\", line 893, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\_set_output.py\", line 140, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\compose\\_column_transformer.py\", line 724, in fit_transform
    self._validate_column_callables(X)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\compose\\_column_transformer.py\", line 426, in _validate_column_callables
    transformer_to_input_indices[name] = _get_column_indices(X, columns)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\__init__.py\", line 416, in _get_column_indices
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: all features must be in [0, 156] or [-157, 0]
",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File g:\\My Drive\\GitHub_Projects\\Balance_data_processing\\Balance_hyperparameter_tuning_v4.py:267
    265 # ...
    266 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 267     features_sfs = main()

File g:\\My Drive\\GitHub_Projects\\Balance_data_processing\\Balance_hyperparameter_tuning_v4.py:249
    246 [X, y] = read_data()
    248 # Sequential feature selection
--> 249 features_sfs = select_sfs(X, y, 'Random_Forest', 'backward', 'roc_auc')
    251 # Recursive feature elimination
    252 #X_selected = select_rfe(X, y, 'random_forest', 'balanced_accuracy')
    253 
   (...)
    260 # To do the gridsearch
    261 #grid = grid_search(X_selected, y, 'Random_Forest', 'roc_auc')
    263 return features_sfs

File g:\\My Drive\\GitHub_Projects\\Balance_data_processing\\Balance_hyperparameter_tuning_v4.py:126
    124 sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(pipe, n_features_to_select = 20, direction = sfs_direction, scoring = sfs_scoring)
    125 # To fit and transform
--> 126 X_transformed = sfs.fit_transform(X, np.ravel(y))
    127 # get features
    128 features_sfs = list(sfs.get_feature_names_out())

File c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\_set_output.py:140, in _wrap_method_output.<locals>.wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    138 @wraps(f)
    139 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 140     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    141     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    142         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
    143         return (
    144             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
    145             *data_to_wrap[1:],
    146         )

File c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\base.py:881, in TransformerMixin.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    878     return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    879 else:
    880     # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 881     return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

File c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\feature_selection\\_sequential.py:276, in SequentialFeatureSelector.fit(self, X, y)
    274 is_auto_select = self.tol is not None and self.n_features_to_select == \"auto\"
    275 for _ in range(n_iterations):
--> 276     new_feature_idx, new_score = self._get_best_new_feature_score(
    277         cloned_estimator, X, y, current_mask
    278     )
    279     if is_auto_select and ((new_score - old_score) < self.tol):
    280         break

File c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\feature_selection\\_sequential.py:307, in SequentialFeatureSelector._get_best_new_feature_score(self, estimator, X, y, current_mask)
    305         candidate_mask = ~candidate_mask
    306     X_new = X[:, candidate_mask]
--> 307     scores[feature_idx] = cross_val_score(
    308         estimator,
    309         X_new,
    310         y,
    311         cv=self.cv,
    312         scoring=self.scoring,
    313         n_jobs=self.n_jobs,
    314     ).mean()
    315 new_feature_idx = max(scores, key=lambda feature_idx: scores[feature_idx])
    316 return new_feature_idx, scores[new_feature_idx]

File c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\model_selection\\_validation.py:515, in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    512 # To ensure multimetric format is not supported
    513 scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
--> 515 cv_results = cross_validate(
    516     estimator=estimator,
    517     X=X,
    518     y=y,
    519     groups=groups,
    520     scoring={\"score\": scorer},
    521     cv=cv,
    522     n_jobs=n_jobs,
    523     verbose=verbose,
    524     fit_params=fit_params,
    525     pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch,
    526     error_score=error_score,
    527 )
    528 return cv_results[\"test_score\"]

File c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\model_selection\\_validation.py:285, in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    265 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose, pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
    266 results = parallel(
    267     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    268         clone(estimator),
   (...)
    282     for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups)
    283 )
--> 285 _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    287 # For callabe scoring, the return type is only know after calling. If the
    288 # return type is a dictionary, the error scores can now be inserted with
    289 # the correct key.
    290 if callable(scoring):

File c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\model_selection\\_validation.py:367, in _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    360 if num_failed_fits == num_fits:
    361     all_fits_failed_message = (
    362         f\"\
All the {num_fits} fits failed.\
\"
    363         \"It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.\
\"
    364         \"You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.\
\
\"
    365         f\"Below are more details about the failures:\
{fit_errors_summary}\"
    366     )
--> 367     raise ValueError(all_fits_failed_message)
    369 else:
    370     some_fits_failed_message = (
    371         f\"\
{num_failed_fits} fits failed out of a total of {num_fits}.\
\"
    372         \"The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters\"
   (...)
    376         f\"Below are more details about the failures:\
{fit_errors_summary}\"
    377     )

ValueError: 
All the 5 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\__init__.py\", line 414, in _get_column_indices
    idx = _safe_indexing(np.arange(n_columns), key)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\__init__.py\", line 356, in _safe_indexing
    return _array_indexing(X, indices, indices_dtype, axis=axis)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\__init__.py\", line 185, in _array_indexing
    return array[key] if axis == 0 else array[:, key]
IndexError: index 157 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 157

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\model_selection\\_validation.py\", line 686, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\imblearn\\pipeline.py\", line 293, in fit
    Xt, yt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\imblearn\\pipeline.py\", line 240, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\joblib\\memory.py\", line 349, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\pipeline.py\", line 893, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\_set_output.py\", line 140, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\compose\\_column_transformer.py\", line 724, in fit_transform
    self._validate_column_callables(X)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\compose\\_column_transformer.py\", line 426, in _validate_column_callables
    transformer_to_input_indices[name] = _get_column_indices(X, columns)
  File \"c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\__init__.py\", line 416, in _get_column_indices
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: all features must be in [0, 156] or [-157, 0]
"
}
```

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74899725/valueerror-all-features-must-be-in-0-20-or-21-0, it seems quite similar

Comment: What's the traceback of this error?

Comment: I added the traceback of the error, thanks Nick